How can I dynamically set text value to a Django form ChoiceField?
I have this ChoiceField in a Django form:
forms.py
sales_documents_description_1 = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=list(models_products.objects.values_list( 'id_product','product_denomination')), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'sales_documents_editable_select_description_1','style': 'width:200px','onchange': 'populate_selected_product(this.id,this.value)'}))

In my template, how do I set the value of this ChoiceField by specifying the text argument (NOT THE VALUE).
I tried with this :
Template.html
# The ChoiceField is rendered like this : 

{{ form5.sales_documents_description_1 }}


     $('#sales_documents_description_1').filter(function() {return $(this).text() == 'Neumann U87';}).prop('selected', true);

or
$("#sales_documents_description_1 option").filter(function(){return $(this).text() == 'Neumann U87';}).prop('selected', true);

But it's not working.
Any JS or jQuery solution will be ok for me.

The second attempt works for me when correcting the typo (there should be a space after the return keyword).

I corrected the typo but even so, still not changing the slectbox selection to 'Neumann U87'

What is the resulting HTML for the <select>?  Is it a native <select> or is some plugin customizing it?

There is no  item in my template as I'm rendering it like this {{ form5.sales_documents_description_1 }}

In the code shown you're attempting to select <option> elements, which are valid only as children of <select> or <optgroup> or <datalist> elements.  Regardless of the server-side code used to generate your HTML, the client-side code is interacting with the resulting HTML.  You'll want to examine what that HTML is when writing code to interact with it.

I inspected the HTM element and I do have Neumann U87

If it's using a <select> but wrapping it in a plugin of some kind to hide the native element and replace it with a custom UI then updating the element may not be enough, you may need to interact with whatever that plugin is.  (e.g. jQuery plugins like Select2)  This may require more Django-specific knowledge that I don't have (more than HTML/JavaScript knowledge).

I'm not using any plugin ... just a regular Django form field

Woops, you a re right I used the wrong ID. attrs={'id': 'sales_documents_editable_select_description_1'. Now the second attempt is working. So stupid ... Thanks a lot for helping me
